# smbus with i2c givees an error saying an integer is required

Tags: python, i2c

I am trying to program the Gpios of the MCP23017 via the i2c bus using the smbus module.. However my write command keeps giving an IO error saying an integer is required..

This is my code:

```
import smbus
bus=smbus.SMBus(1)

ADDR=0x20
IODIRA=0x00
high=0xFF

bus.write_byte_data(ADDR, IODIRA, high)
```

The error i get is :

```
bus.write_byte_data(ADDR, IODIRA, high)
TypeError: an integer is required.
```

Here what I do not understand is the integer it refers to in the error is for the value 'high' or for the IODIRA?
I have also tried to put in the code as

```
bus.write_byte_data(ADDR, 0x00, 0xFF)
```

But it still gives me the sam error

Could somebody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Char is not the same as int. pass something like 255